# Check total ADA delegated to the pool with cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, stake-pool, staking

I'm running the stake pool and want to know the delegators count and total amount of ADA delegated to my pool.
Is there a way to do that from my producer/relay node using `cardano-cli`?
I know this info can be obtained from resources like https://adapools.org/, but is there any internal statistics that provide such details (e.g. for my monitoring tools to fetch)

Answer (score 3):

you can obtain a snapshot information using the `cardano-cli`:

```
cardano-cli query stake-snapshot --stake-pool-id POOL_ID --mainnet
```

which returns the following

```
{
"poolStakeGo": 12016106401607,
"activeStakeGo": 14925992640911949,
"activeStakeMark": 14854196369191645,
"poolStakeMark": 12021194972631,
"activeStakeSet": 14853022119978909,
"poolStakeSet": 12018867311903
```

}

`Go` - 2 epochs ago

`Set` - 1 epoch ago

`Mark` - snapshot for the current epoch

To get the more detailed information about the delegator count you'd need to query `cardano-db-sync`